# Where does the normal terminal output go to when a script is started by init.d?

Tags: python, init.d

I've a Python script which runs OK manually. I've started it on boot init.d. It runs, but exits. Can you tell me where the normal terminal output goes in this case? There's debug output I've sent to the screen which would help me.

** UPDATE ** in fact, it's quite spurious. It does run every time manually, but off the boot, sometimes it runs perfectly, sometimes it doesn't. I've added some manual logging. When it stops, it's in random places: sometimes just after importing a module, sometimes just after initialising GPIO.

Comment: `"It runs, but exists."`??   Did you mean, **"It runs, but exits."**?

Comment: That's the one.

Answer (score 2):

The systemd journal may have caught that, I think it does handle stuff in `/etc/init.d` as a service, but this may depend a bit on how properly you did it -- which is not worth much discussion because using init.d is very deprecated at this point.

But check `systemctl list-units | grep [basename of the script]`, by "basename" I mean the name without .py or .sh suffix.  If it shows, you might get the output from the last run via `sudo journalctl -xeu [name of service you just found]`.

However, a better way to do this is to wrap it in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -t 0 ]; then
    exec &> /var/log/myscript.log
fi

/full/path/to/the/script
```

You can accomplish the same thing directly in python but it is a little more awkward, I think. `-t 0` just checks if stdin is associated with a terminal (which it will be if you run it from the commandline, but not via init/systemd).  If not it redirects all subsequent output (stdin and stderr) to a file.  See also `man test` (`test` is applied by the shell to stuff inside `[ ]`).

If you'd rather just move this to systemd, here's a basic service file that should work:

```
[Unit]
Description=Whatever you want
Requires=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/myscript.log
ExecStart=/path/to/myscript.py

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

You can also use `file` in place of `append` to overwrite the log each run.  Stderr will go to the same place.  The various directives (`Requires`, `Type`, etc.) are documented in man pages, to look one up use `man systemd.directives` (for a list of all pages, see `man systemd.index`).

Put that file in `/etc/systemd/system` with the suffix service (eg. `myscript.service` and enable it `sudo systemctl enable myscript.service`, then check `systemctl status myscript`.  If you change anything in the service file at some point (such as one of the paths), run `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Comment: "deprecated" rather than "depreciated" You can test the `tty` (or any) command directly without using `$?`: `if tty > /dev/null 2>&1; then` or you can use the shell's terminal test: `if [ -t 0 ]; then` instead of using `tty` at all. The zero is `stdin`.

Comment: Actually, this makes some sense: this is a fresh install of a program I wrote years ago. It works OKay on BUSTER, but this is my trying it on BULLSEYE. Could explain some other odd behaviours: when I use update-rc.d with "remove" it still tries to run at boot time! I suppose this means I need to look at systemd.

Comment: Systemd is easier to use and much more feature rich.  WRT "remove", look through symlinks to it in /etc/rc[0-6].d/.  They will be prefixed with "Knn" or "Snn" where nn is a two digit number.  Delete those and remove it from `/etc/init.d` and it should not run that way anymore.  I'll add a simple example of how to use systemd instead.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thx for that, I actually did not know those were two distinct words o_O